# How to format a USB stick who have write protection error

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, windows-7

I have a USB stick wich suddenly, when I was copying some files gave me a write protection error.
Since then I can use it only to read files, not to write(but in Ubuntu it works to create a new file and folder but I can't delete it), and I can't format it, if I tried it show some errors like that:

[image]

[image]

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7, have anyone any idea how I can make it work?